# Automatically fetch information from OleDB Access

Tags: c#, oledb

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\`Hp\Desktop\PROGRAM1\notificationSystem\notificationSystem\Database.accdb";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = cn;

//reg();

cn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "select article from news where npublished = '" + metroDateTime1.Text + "' AND ntime = '" + label4.Text + "'";
//AND ntime = '" + label4.Text + "'

//Scalar executes the fetching of data
var a = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

//this statement gets the process of getting the data from the database to label          
if (a != null)
{
    label1.Text = "" + a.ToString();

    //while in this statement is displaying the data inside the textbox
    metroTextBox2.Text = label1.Text;
}
else if (metroTextBox2.Text != null)
{
    //SEND SMS PROCESS
}
else if (metroTextBox2.Text == null)
{
    //REPEAT FETCH
}
cn.Close();
```

So the code above works but I use a button, and I have to press the button everytime to fetch information. Does anyone have any advice on what should I do to automatically fetch information from database using datagridview and display it on textbox?

I want to put the code on form load, so everytime I will run the program it will automatically fetch and do its job. But I don't know how to do it and I tried but it won't work.

Any help is gradly appreciated.

Comment: Use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and call your update method there.

Comment: I tried using timer but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" means? does it throw any error? It does not update your label? Set a Break Point in your method and debug it step by step to see what is happening

Comment: What do you mean by break point?

Comment: Debugging is the most important thing you should learn. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: Yes indeed, i know how to debug and i tried methods like timer so putting an action so every 1 sec the action will fire. But it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error or what.. It just doesn't work with the timer i tried and i need help with automatic fetch using other methods.